# Vim autocorrection problem

Tags: vimrc, neovim, spell-checking

I am having a problem with vim autocorrection. I got this line from a [website](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/), which is:

```
inoremap <C-l> <Esc>[s1z=`]a
```

The problem is that whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to correct something, it brings me to the end of the file, but I want it to bring the cursor back to where I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My version of the mapping (which mostly works, unless the replacement made the text longer, in which case you end up in the wrong spot), is as follows (`<C-g>u` used to break up the undo sequence):

```
inoremap <C-L> <C-g>u<Esc>[s1z=gi<C-g>u
```

`gi` should work slightly better than the `]` mark, which is the last-changed text.